# How to check a radio button programmatically?

Tags: radio-button, swt

I set up a dialog with 2 radio buttons, and use a boolean to check them programmatically.

```
    // Not working day radio button
    final Button notWorkingDayButton = new Button(mSelectedDayGroup, SWT.RADIO);
    notWorkingDayButton.setSelection(isWorkingDay);
    notWorkingDayButton.setText("Jour chômé"+(isHoliday ? deft : ""));

    // Working day radio button
    final Button workingDayButton = new Button(mSelectedDayGroup, SWT.RADIO);
    workingDayButton.setText("Jour travaillé"+(isHoliday ? "" : deft));
    workingDayButton.setSelection(!isWorkingDay);
```

As you can see, they use the same `boolean` so they always have opposed states.

Here's how it looks like if `isWorkingDay` is `true`: [image: isWorkingDay=true]

Here's how it looks like if `isWorkingDay` is `false`: [image: isWorkingDay=false]

As you can see the first radio stays somewhat enabled. I want the first one to be completely disabled and the second one completely enabled when `isWorkingDay = false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Mac but this looks like the keyboard focus to me. There is no "somewhat enabled" state for radio buttons.

Comment: That's right, it is the keyboard focus. Then my question should be read as: How to change the keyboard focus state of a radio button?

Comment: The only way to remove the focus is to assign it to another control, e.g. your OK button.